# Verification of function that sums array of int vs array of float using FramaC/WP

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to specify and verify this simple function that sums up an array.
This specification for an array of ints is accepted by WP:

```
/*@ axiomatic Sum_Int {
      logic int sum_int(int *values, integer begin, integer end)
          reads values[begin .. (end - 1)];

      axiom empty_int:
        \forall int *p, integer begin, end; begin >= end
            ==> sum_int(p, begin, end) == 0;

      axiom range_int:
        \forall int *p, integer begin, end; begin < end
            ==> sum_int(p, begin, end) == sum_int(p, begin, end - 1) + p[end - 1];
}
*/

/*@ requires \valid_read(values + (0 .. size - 1));

    assigns \nothing;

    ensures \result == sum_int(values, 0, size);
*/
int sum_int_array(const int *values, size_t size) {
    int sum = 0;
    /*@ loop invariant 0 <= index <= size;
        loop invariant sum == sum_int(values, 0, index);
        loop assigns sum, index;
        loop variant size - index;
    */
    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        sum += values[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

But the same specification for an array of floats cannot be proven by WP:

```
/*@ axiomatic Sum_Real {
      logic float sum_real(float *values, integer begin, integer end)
          reads values[begin .. (end - 1)];

      axiom empty_real:
        \forall float *p, integer begin, end; begin >= end
            ==> sum_real(p, begin, end) == 0;

      axiom range_real:
        \forall float *p, integer begin, end; begin < end
            ==> sum_real(p, begin, end) == sum_real(p, begin, end - 1) + p[end - 1];
}
*/

/*@ requires \valid_read(values + (0 .. size - 1));

    requires \forall integer i; 0 <= i < size ==> \is_finite(values[i]);
    assigns \nothing;

    ensures \result == sum_real(values, 0, size);
*/
float sum_float_array(const float *values, size_t size) {
    float sum = 0;
    /*@ loop invariant 0 <= index <= size;
        loop invariant sum == sum_real(values, 0, index);
        loop assigns sum, index;
        loop variant size - index;
    */
    for (size_t index = 0; index < size; index++) {
        sum += values[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The axiomatic definition is the same (and I think it should be the same, if it is correct). The only difference is the added precondition for the float array:

```
requires \forall integer i; 0 <= i < size ==> \is_finite(values[i]);
```

Which I am not sure if it is necessary.
What information is missing here for WP to be able to verify the float version?

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395783/how-do-i-prove-code-with-a-real-axiomatic-in-frama-c? This seems quite related.

Comment: As @byako says, your issue is exactly the one mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53398201/1633665), i.e. the addition in `range_real` axiom is performed with real arithmetic instead of floating-point. If you cast the result of the operation into `float`, everything will work fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prove code with a real axiomatic in Frama-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395783/how-do-i-prove-code-with-a-real-axiomatic-in-frama-c)